# Difference between "Why is this so?" and "Give reasons for this and solutions?"

Tags: writing, ielts, academic-writing

In IELTS writing task 2, I saw some questions such as the following,

> Why is this so? Give reasons for this and solutions?

Here, the IDP asked to answer in the following essay structure (paragraph-wise):

> Para-1. Introduction
> Para-2. Reason why it is so
> Para-3. Reasons for this
> Para-4. Solutions for this
> Para-5. Conclusion

What is the difference between *Why it is so* and *Reasons for this*? (I don't see any difference between Paragraph 2 and 3.)

Comment: Could the test writers simply be bored with asking the question the same way many times?

Comment: I don't see any difference either. Incidentally, _Give reasons for this and solutions_ is an instruction, so it shouldn't have a question mark.

Comment: @KateBunting I would view "give reasons for this and solutions" as elaborating what, exactly, should be contained in the essay (no question mark needed), while "Why is this so?" is the "high-level" main question.

Comment: It might be clearer if you gave an actual example of a question in this format.  I'd suggest that you might consider "immediate causes" and "underlying causes".  Eg "Streets are too busy": immediate cause is "too many cars", underlying cause is "too many people in the city". Solutions "fewer cars and fewer people"...

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simply, what is being asked for is:

1. a summary explanation outlining the most superficial cause(s) behind what is happening
2. further details supporting that summary explanation, explaining the factors and / or chain of events leading to those causes